# Getting the ID of the ListView Item when it is populated from a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I am developing an android app in which user fills a form by selecting CREATE NEW from a list view and the form is stored in a SQLite database and appears on listview. It is like this

Starting only CREATE NEW
After filling a forms ListView will be like

CREATE NEW

FORM1

FORM2

Each form refers a record in a database table

Now What I want to do is.
If I click on Form1 it should open for the user to edit and so on.
I am using the position of the listview to match with primary id of the record and showing the respective record

But the whole problem is coming when I delete records

Is there any more elegant method to get the ID of the ListView Item when it is populated from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an item is clicked, you can get it's id in this way:
Set an OnItemClickListener to the listView and then you get the id:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) 
        {
            // Do whatever you want. "id" as the id in the db.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select all the records inside your db, I mean without any conditions then the position of the form in the query will be the same position inside the database, but if you have condition in your query than you only get the position of your form inside the you conditional query. You've mentioned clicking, so in the `setOnItemClickListener()` you have int position variable that specifies item position in the `ListView`, sometimes there are cases where you have half visible items, then you can apply the formula `positon = position - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();` thus you avoid scrambling the data with the position. Also in the `getView()` also you can make a use of the same `int position` variable. I hope this is reasonable.

When you delete records you can signal the `ListView` to repopulate itself. With the current and  new data (same data minus deleted record form the adapter) also you can signal (execute query to delete that record) the database to delete the record, if this is what you are looking for.